# Error install Angular 4 using npm

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

When i install angular and try to use this command line : 
     ng -v i got an error (check jpeg file) ..
I have installed : node 6.10.3
someone have a solution

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those errors are caused by you manually stopped `@angular/cli` from installing packages into your project folder.(When running `ng -v` in a `angular/cli` project folder, `angular/cli` will trying to output your version information of installed `@angular/xxx` packages).

mention that when you pressed `Ctrl + C`, the task will stop even you pressed `N` later.

**Solution:**

run `npm install` at your project folder and wait for it to be finished, then when you run `ng -v` again, the errors will gone.

Comment: ok thanks; but i can't test it because I got an other error when i run this command :                                                                                        C:\Users\fretea\Desktop\AngularTrain>ng new TrainAngular
You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project. and when i tried the command ng -v I got : 
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: error
@angular/compiler: error
@angular/core: error
@angular/forms: error
@angular/http: error
@angular/platform-browser: etc ..

Comment: @user1814879 you don't have to run `ng new` again because the project is already generated. just run `npm install` and `ng -v`

Comment: Ok, but i removed all project all projetc and initialize a new.. so i need it . for example I want to create angular/cli project by this commands :  1 - npm install -g @angular/cli  2-ng new PROJECT-NAME

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Why when i trie thi command : ng new myprojeect I got error (You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI projec)

Comment: @user1814879 still the same problem,  you are already in an `angular/cli` project folder. you have to move to another folder or delete the current one.